# CBM image file format: what is it? how to read it?

Tags: image, file-io, file-format, xlib, javax.imageio

I have a collection of images in the **CBM** file format.
What is this format? How to read it? How to convert it to, say, a BMP bitmap?

Searching the net, I found that it could mean one of those three things:

1) **Fuzzy Bitmap**, as per Michael Mauldin's library, FBM (1989). The softwares XnView and Graphics Convert Pro 2011 should be able to open it, but they don't. Most likely it means that the file I have is not really a Fuzzy Bitmap.

2) **Compiled bitmap**, as per XLib ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats_%28alphabetical%29))
How to proceed in order to test that my file is such a Compiled Bitmap? Where to download XLib / what should I build?

3) **Compressed Bitmap**. Do you have more info's on this format?

Comment: How old are the files? What platform were they made on? Who made them? What are they images of?

Comment: Notes about the [CBM file extension](http://filext.com/file-extension/CBM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [CreateDIBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. If you pass correct parameters, you should be able to save it into some more known file format.

Here you can find something about [Bitmap Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you don't know image details like resolution, bitsperpixel, compression type,... It will be hard to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe CBMs are just Zip files renamed. Try renaming and unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

try to open it with konvertor (www.konvertor.net); it does read several CBMs formats

Comment: Konvertor creates a white image with some black ASCII characters in it. Confusing.